# Prevent edge creation in Cytoscape JS + EdgeHandles

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

What is the best way to prevent creating more than one edge from **node A** to **node B**?

I'm currently using a map (plain JSON object) to keep track of added edges and if an edge from **A** to **B** already exists I delete it, but it doesn't look very elegant as solution.

I thought I found the solution looking at the *edgeType* event, as it takes a source node and a target node as parameter, returning null/undefined would prevent the addition of the edge. The problem is I actually don't get a target *node* but another kind of object, making this event useless. I can't understand what is useful for, it seems a bug actually.

Answer (score 2):

Another kind of object may be edgeHandle object.It will have only id attribute in its data. you can ignore it by adding some condition. But if you mouse over on real target node, this edgeHandle element will be replaced with element(node) on which you did mouse over.

```
getEdgeType = (srcNode, tgtNode) => { 
    if (tgtNode.data() && tgtNode.data().isDiagramNode) 
        // isDiagramNode is a property of the diagram node data object 
        // you can add your logic and return either 'flat' or null 
    }
    return null; // null means cant make link between nodes 
};
```

Comment: getEdgeType = (srcNode, tgtNode) => {
   
    if (tgtNode.data() && tgtNode.data().isDiagramNode)  // here isDiagramNode is property in diagram node data object ....here u can add your logic and return either 'flat' or null                                                                                         
    }
    return null; // null means cant make link between nodes
  };